# Convert Ubuntu desktop to server edition (20.04)

Tags: server, 20.04

I'm relative new user using Ubuntu (20.04), and I want to know the steps to follow to convert an Ubuntu desktop installation that I already on a VM to a server edition without re-installing entirely the OS with the server edition ISO file.

Please, let me know.

Answer (score 12):

Step 1: `sudo apt install ubuntu-server`.

That's it. There is no Step 2.

Comment: Thanks dude. Installing this package will remove desktop environment (GUI) right ?.

Comment: No: You did not ask for that. That's MUCH more difficult; it involves laboriously changing the apt-marking of many dozens of packages. It's a safeguard specifically to prevent folks from accidentally uninstalling their desktop.

Comment: Thanks dude. (y). So, is more reliable installing ubuntu server edition to avoid all unnecesary packages from the desktop one.

Comment: Useful Step 2 is `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` to save some RAM and CPU resources for not used graphical session.

Comment: Thanks for share this N0rbert.

Comment: I take that "Step 2" above is for those **not** intending to use the the computer in "Desktop mode".

Comment: @user535733 but imagine I want to move to ubuntu server to save space on disk by removing GUI packages, how do I do that? Thanks

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira since reinstalling (the easiest method) is specifically rejected by the question, you must tediously change the apt-marking of several hundred packages making up the entire desktop stack. The apt-marking of those hundreds of desktop dependencies must be set to 'auto' so they will autoremove, which provides the bulk of your recovered disk space. You could also apt-remove those packages directly, which is just as tedious...and also risks erroneous removal of something critical. It's generally not worthwhile -- removing ALL desktop packages might free up only a couple GB.

Comment: Once _ubuntu-server_ is installed and _multi-user.target_ is default, and you rebooted into Console, removing the X Server should get rid of most of the Desktop environment. Additionally, things like Gnome, X11 and Unity (if you upgraded from earlier Ubuntu versions, like I did) are things to look for. `apt purge ubuntu-desktop xwayland xserver-* x11-* xinit unity-* gnome* && apt autoremove --purge`. There may still be more GUI-related packages lingering though.

Answer (score 11):

Here is what I did to make it all work and also clean it up a bit.

1. sudo apt install ubuntu-server
2. reboot
3. sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
4. reboot
5. sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean
6. reboot

Some steps were taken from https://www.techandme.se/completley-remove-ubuntu-desktop-from-a-ubuntu-server/

Comment: This is a really cool, minimalistic and good answer :) I like it

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the output of `sudo apt list --installed` on a server installation vs. a desktop installation, there are a few more packages installed with the desktop then with the server variant.

At first sight, I saw e.g. `ubuntu-minimal-desktop ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mono ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-report ubuntu-session ubuntu-wallpapers-jammy ubuntu-wallpapers`, I also ran `sudo apt purge xorg-docs-core xorg xserver-*` to get rid of the xserver things. Don't forget `sudo apt autoremove` to kick out now unused libraries.

And after all this, there are still a few(hundred) packages left to remove to make a server installation out of a desktop.

If you are intended to use the installation as production environment it's definitely worth to go through the list an clean everything up, because every unused package is a potential security vulnerability.

For educational purpose, [Jonathan's](https://askubuntu.com/a/1415282/1127387) steps are sufficient.